# HttpParams change "equal to" to "greater than or equal to"

Tags: angular, http

I am using Angular 5 with the new **HttpClient** to perform an HTTP GET request with query parameters. Currently it creates the query parameters with an equals `param1=20`. Is it possible to change it so that for specific parameters it will be `param1>=20`?

```
const room = {
  name: "A1"
  seats: 20
};

// currently it will do: '?name=A1&seats=20' but I need it to be like: '?name=A1&seats>=20'
const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: room});
this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {params: httpParams});
```

Comment: Nop, https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/params.ts#L177 thats pretty much the standard structure for a query string

Comment: That's just not how query parameters work. If you want to implement those semantics, do it on the server side. Maybe change the name to `minSeats` to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the end-result you want:

```
const room = {
  name: "A1"
  "seats>": 20
};


const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: room});
this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {params: httpParams});
```

This will result in Angular's HttpClient generating the following query parameters: `name=A1&seats%3E=20` (which decoded will equal `name=A1&seats>=20`).

Keep in mind that on the server-side you will have to access the query parameter value as `seats>`. In Node.js Express it will be `req.params['seats>']`. Since the `=` is a special character when encoding a query string, it will always be removed, so if you are expecting to receive something as `seats>=` (greater or equal than) on the server side, you won't be able to do that. Instead, if you want to support such criteria, you can encode it as `variablename_{condition}` where `condition` is:

- `gte` - greater than or equal
- `gt` - greater than
- `lte` - less than or equal
- `lt` - less than

I would advice you not to use symbols which get encoded (like `>`) because it will be a lot easier to read the meaning of query string for humans.

Compare:
`seats_gt=20&seats_lt=30` versus `seats%3E=20&seats%3C=30`. Which one is more readable to you?